# Where do I insert the exit tile in a 1-2 player game

Tags: escape-the-curse-of-the-temple

In Escape: The Curse of the Temple, the rules say if you are playing 1-2 players to

> insert the exit tile in the middle of the draw pile

With the base game (I'm assuming expansions maybe add to this pile), there are 15 tiles left at this point after putting 2 of them next to the entrance. Where does the exit tile go, above the 8th tile or below it?

Answer (score 1):

From the Rulebook

[image: Rulebook Clip]

> **Setup**
>
> 1. You will need the **6 main chambers** and the **13 basic chambers** **(that is, all the chambers without the purple mask and/or treasure icon)**. Set aside the **starting chamber** and **exit**. Mix the **remaining chamber tiles** face down, then stack them as a draw pile. Place the starting chamber in the center of the playing area, then place 2 randomly drawn chamber tiles next to it, as shown in the illustration below. Finally, take the top 4 tiles of the **draw pile**, shuffle them together with the exit tile, then place them on the bottom of the draw pile.
>
> **Exception:** If you are playing alone or with a second player, insert the exit tile in the middle of the draw pile.

Considering the rather loose and light nature of the game. I don't expect that the instruction was meant to be literal. But if you need a ruling I would remove half the pile. Place the Exit Tile and then call that done. So with 15 tile. Remove 8 tiles (7.5 rounded up) place the exit tile and then now you have two piles. 8 regular and 8 including the exit.